# Vibrations or not depending on phone position

Tags: settings, htc-wildfire, vibration, profiles

Is there any chance to disable phone vibrations when phone is in straight horizontal position? (eg. on the table).

I want to have vibrations turned on only when I have it in my pocket, close to the body, in other situations turned off.

Is there any app for this? Maybe there is some profile switcher based on the phone position?

Answer (score 2):

You could do that with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). This app matches defined conditions with tasks -- i.e. you can tell it to execute a task (which is a set of actions) whenever a (set of) condition(s) is met.

Under [conditions](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html) it lists "Orientation".

As [actions](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html), it e.g. describes:

> **Vibrate On Notify:** Whether to vibrate with a system notification.
>   **Vibrate On Ringer:** Whether to vibrate on an incoming call.

So you could create a task named, say, *NoVibrate*, which says:

- Vibrate on Notify: Off
- Vibrate on Ringer: Off

Then create two profiles *FaceUp* and *FaceDown* (there's no "OR" connection possible with conditions, hence you need two profiles), each with the respective orientation, and have them execute the *NoVibrate* task.

What happens then? As soon as the phone is FaceUp or FaceDown (where "face" is the display), vibration is turned off. And as soon the orientation changes, the prior setting gets re-activated.

Problem solved with the 6-letter-solver of (almost) all Android problems: Tasker :)